# remove imported css file in vue project

Tags: vue.js

In my vue app there's a dynamic class - `.ltr` which i toggle according to user language selection.

the css in my `App.vue` is as follows:

```
<style lang="scss">
@import "./assets/css/style.css";

.ltr {
  @import "./assets/css/ltr.css";
}
</style>
```

the goal was to load the `ltr.css` file when the root div has the class `ltr` and unload/reset/? the file when the class is removed.
the problem is after i import the file it's content stay's in the DOM regardless of what happens with the `ltr` class. any idea how can i load/unload this css file?

Comment: Once the styles are in the browser, they are there... I guess you could unset the values of properties you don't want.